# Html to Canvas to Base64 to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, html2canvas

So I'm trying to work out a way to convert html to pdf entirely on the clients side, somewhere I read that you can convert a base64 to a pdf on the client side, and from there I remembered you can create a canvas from html and a Base 64 from a Canvas. So I got everything working up until converting the base64 to pdf. I cant seem to get the last part to work. Here is my code

```
var element =  document.getElementById('canvas1');
        console.log(element);
if (typeof(element) == 'undefined' || element == null)
{
        html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    $('canvas').attr( 'id', 'canvas1' );
  }
});
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); // PNG is the default
console.log("jp"+jpegUrl);
console.log("png"+pngUrl);
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + pngUrl);
console.log('new');
},500);
```

I'm using the html2canvas library to convert the html to canvas and attach it to the body, and so far that works flawlessly. But why cant I convert the base64 to pdf. It just opens a blank page with the url "data:" as if its not loading the base64 string with it. Any help would be appreciated, I might be over thinking this and im sure there is an easier way. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q582/) of the problem.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415665/save-base64-string-as-pdf-at-client-side-with-javascript  Or maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url ?

Comment: The first one I have tryed to implement using the base64 transcoder but still get nothing. and the second one looks to be doing the opposite of what im trying to do. It looks like it wants to take a pdf to render the page from my understanding.

Comment: you are right, the second one is the opposite but I figured the API may lead somewhere.  Can you post a fiddle to see how the issue behaves?

Comment: Are you using cross-domain images?  If so you might be causing CORS security violations that causes canvas.toDataURL to fail: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html

Comment: No, everything is being done on localhost, so there is no interaction with the server or other domains. Also the datatourl call is returning a string. It's just not being passed to the window.open call.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q582/) you might have to enable popups.

Comment: So it appears it is passing it the base64 string but it still shows "failed to load pdf document"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Problem

I guess first off, we'll go through what's wrong with your code I guess. First of all, rather than `setTimeout`, the "pdf-ing" code should be inside `onRendered` as potentially, you might find that the code runs before the canvas could be rendered.

Next, how you're prefixing the PDF from the datauri. with a `data:application/pdf;base64,`. Canvas outputs the full datauri already. For example `data:image/PNG;base64,BASE64DATAHERE...`. What your're doing is prefixing the `data:application/pdf:base64,` so it'll look like `data:application/pdf:base64,data:image/PNG;base64,BASE64DATAHERE...` which is wrong. You need to replace the prefixes completely. I made a simple [demo of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/nyLjC/) where I replaced a `PNG` datauri with `jpeg`.

Code is

```
//datauri is an image with a datauri of a png
prefixJpg.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+datauri.src
replaceJpg.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+datauri.src.substring(22) 
//remove the first 22 characters
```

The output should look like

[image]

The prefixing one cannot be rendered as it's not a valid base64 image data.

Continuing on, looking at the output, we note that, the image with the `jpeg` datauri, has transparent background. JPEG can't have transparent background. So in essence, the data is still PNG, and only because lenient renderer that the browser accepts that though it says it's jpeg it's actually still png, and still show it.

This brings us to the final problem with your code. As far as I know, in most cases, you can't actually convert something by just changing the datauri. I tried testing this by manually changing an image datauri to a datauri with pdf prefix. Chrome loaded it's builtin pdf plugin but it "failed to load".

---

### Solution

Looking around there's actually a pdf writer written in javascript:

### jsPDF

It has a pdf rendered that you can use and has all sorts of methods that you can look at. As an example, you can create a pdf from a datauri with the `.addImage()` method. [I updated your code to use jsPDF](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/8Q582/3/).

```
 html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    var marginLeft=20;
    var marginRight=20
    pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),"jpeg",marginLeft,marginRight)
    window.location=pdf.output("datauristring")
  }
});
```

And it seems to work well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately pdfJS doesnt seem to be a good solution for my specific problem. When using the .fromHTML function pdfJS seems to ignore all styling attributes, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q582/2/). So although it does generate the pdf like I want, it loses alot in its conversion process.

Comment: There's probably a way to use the `.fromHTML`but I guess for quick fix and in answering you question, jsPDF (sorry I misnamed the thing) has an `addImage()`. I'll update my answer