# Download base64 PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, filesaver.js

I am receiving from the server the following response:

```
Object {
  $type: "base64",
  $data: "JVBERi0xLjQK..."
}
```

I try to autodownload it with [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

```
    let arrayBuffer = atob(response.$data);
    let blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: "application/pdf;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, 'myfile.pdf');
```

A PDF is generated, and downloads (it has the same page number as the original on the server), but is empty.
However this works:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + response.$data);
```

It opens the PDF with its content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You are not creating the blob correctly, pls read "creating a blob from base64"

Comment: For people who are looking for a solution, it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669785/807101