# Downloading PDF File in Angular Leaves it Blank

Tags: angular, pdf

I am trying to download a PDF from an API, but am running into a little issue. The data seems to come back fine; here's an example of it coming back:

[image: pdf result]

In the Angular app, I'm using the ngx-filesaver package to save the files. It's working with a different PDF, over which I have a little more control than in this case, and with CSVs. So I know that the package works in the right situations. Here's the download file function I'm using:

```
getGroup1094BTaxForm(year: string = '2017') {
    return this._http.get(`${this.groupBaseUrl}/taxes/1094/${year}`, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
            const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            this._fileSaver.save(<any>blob, 'group-1094b.pdf');
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```

I have tried setting the `responseType` to `blob` and `text` on the `GET` request, and then when I create the `blob` after the response comes back I explicitly set it to `application/pdf`. This same issue occurs when I take out the line that creates the blob and just pass the response right into the `_fileSaver.save` function.

What am I missing for how to save the file without it being blank? I checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436133/pdf-is-blank-when-downloading-using-javascript), but none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `responseType` from `text` to `blob`

```
getGroup1094BTaxForm(year: string = '2017') {
    return this._http.get(`${this.groupBaseUrl}/taxes/1094/${year}`, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
            const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            this._fileSaver.save(<any>blob, 'group-1094b.pdf');
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to be more explicit. I have tried this with the `responseType` set to `blob` and `text`, both with the same outcome.

Comment: Did you try with response type `arraybuffer`

Comment: Just did; same result as all the others.

Comment: change `Blob([res]` to `Blob([res._body]`

Comment: That produces an error when opening the file, "Failed to load PDF Document".

Comment: finally try with `Blob([res.body]`. Else I will be share my code which uses `FileSaver`

Comment: The response is the string shown in the picture above; there are no attributes on the response.

Comment: It just returns the response to the component that called this function. I returned that, but I could also return an object,: `{ success: true }` or something like that.

Comment: ok, walk through this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver

Comment: That's for AngularJS (v1.x), right? I need it for Angular (v2.0+) which is why I've been using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver

Comment: Right, you look at that closely. its useing `_body`

Comment: `this._FileSaverService.save((<any>res)._body, fileName);`

Comment: Same "Failed to load PDF Document" error as before when trying to access `.body` or `._body`.

Comment: Now I am doubting on our API response. Just save the API response a file with extension pdf ex test.pdf and check if it is rendering.

Comment: I used the FileSaver.saveAs function from https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver, saving the response directly: `const file = new File([res], 'res-group-1094b.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });`, `saveAs(file)`, and still got the blank page. Using the blob just produced the "Failed to load" error.