# Download file from api in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have ASP.NET Core MVC back-end api. One controller returns File from server. Is there a way to make request to api route by [href] attribute of <a> tag? Looks like it tries to call React route but not make a request to server.

Also I made AJAX call to that controller and got back file as a string (screenshot is attached). Why is it a string, shouldn.t it be a byte array? How to build back file from that string? (it's a .pdf file). I have an empty PDF if use JavaScript new File([], 'name', {options}).

ASP.NET Core controller returns PDF this way:

```
return PhysicalFile(Path.GetFullPath(relativePath), "application/pdf", reportName);
```

In React I receive it as a string this way:

```
let stringPDFBinary = await ReportService.getReport(id, reportFileName)
```

I just need to download file from api by any way. [image]

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Verify me of something. Do you want to download the pdf from your backend API and appear downloaded in your app(browser - lower left corner) correct? i have that code just verify me of that.

Comment: @JúlioAlmeida   I just need to download pdf from API. Asp.net core returns it from controller. In react I receive it throufg AJAX call as it is at screenshot. I have no idea how to make it pdf file again in React and download it.

Comment: @Gh05d Added code

Comment: You can't use AJAX to download file; but you can manually save the generated/ downloaded content (blob). Try using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/Saving-a-remote-file#using-ajax--filesaver)...

Comment: @IronGeek Why can't I use ajax? I did it in angular but can't in react for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is here: [PDF is blank when downloading using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436133/pdf-is-blank-when-downloading-using-javascript)

The same problem. Let it be one more topic, easier to find for others. The AJAX response is encoded string. In request config set 'responseType = 'arraybuffer'' somehow and receiving pdf will not be blank. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I Just copied and pasted from the code source. The problem seems to be the same that i had:

Asp net controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("File")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult GetFile(string key)
    {
        var file = (FileCacheValue)_fileCache.Cache[key.Replace(" ", "+")];

        if (file == null)
            return NotFound();

        Response.Headers["content-disposition"] = $"inline;filename={file.Name}.pdf";

        return File(file.Data, "application/pdf");
    }
```

In this case comes from a cache system. The data is a byte array.

Front-end React:

```
const onClick = () => 
{
   window.open(pdfByteArray, '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
}
```

Exactly what i have. I just put the data on a new window and open the pdf.

The Ajax part is straight forward, get the value from the response and set it on a variable